# Restricting the BLE peripheral device to connect to only one Master

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to restrict my BLE Peripheral device to connect with only one master always .IF i receive a connection request from some other master/central device, it should reject the connection request !

Thanks for your help !

Regards,

Senthil

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague so I break it into two cases:

(1) If it is connected to a master, it can't connect to another. This restriction is imposed by BLE standard.

(2) Probably you meant this one. If it was connected to a master, but due to some reason, the connection was lost and the peripheral is advertising again. You do not want this peripheral to connect to any other central devices in the earshot and still wait its original master, right? Well, your peripheral can only do connectable advertising and respond to whatever central device that initiates a connection request. But once both are connected, your peripheral could ask for whatever information from the master for identification. If the master can't respond with a correct answer, your peripheral could disconnect and do advertising again until the original central device connects to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also have similar problem we have our own BLE device and want it only connect with our own Android app (central), if any, other app (central) is trying to connect with a device that connection should disconnect immediately. How can we achieve this, could you help me.

Comment: @YBDevi I had not worked with BLE and embedded systems since 2014 so I am not able to answer accurately. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the application on the slave then.

Do you have a BLE chip application layer source code?
Do you have a BLE chip programmer? Development kit?
What chip ar you using?