# ble peripheral coded for exclusive central / master use

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Being somewhat of a newbie I was wondering if there is a way to hard-code something on a peripheral that would only allow a single unique central/master to connect.....?

i.e. / eg
I have the ‘simple chat’ Arduino app on a RedBearLab Blend-Micro (which is for all intensive purposes the same as a Arduino Uno with a BLE shield) and I only want one single / unique phone to BE ABLE TO connect with it and therefore work with it.

My understanding is that the GAP handles security features during a BLE connection.

Therefore, is there some way to ‘code’ the peripheral device in / below one of the following includes:
    spi.h ?
    boards.h ?
    EEPROM.h ?
    RBL_nRF8001.h (or similar) ?
Other?

Didn't quite get an answer from [Restricting the BLE peripheral device to connect to only one Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844873)

**OR**

Am I stuck with EVERYTHING connecting but coding the peripheral in some other way in a GATT profile (I think) to ONLY do something with a predefined unique central/master (how/where to code?).

Many thanks for thoughts in advance

Answer (score 0):

*Being somewhat of a newbie I was wondering if there is a way to hard-code something on a peripheral that would only allow a single unique central/master to connect.....?*

Theres the "Advertising Filter Policy" as specified in the [Bluetooth Core V4.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) specification. Its a Byte in the Advertising Parameters as specified in Section `7.8.5 LE Set Advertising Parameters Command`.

For example the value `0x02` reads *Allow Scan Request from Any, Allow Connect Request from White List Only.*

Then theres section `7.8.16 LE Add Device To White List Command`.

That said, if your device confirms to the Bluetooth 4.0 specification, it should support these HCI commands. However there might be functions that simplify these procedures, wrapping those HCI commands for easier use. Check the Documentation of your device for such methods.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to answer this question via email. It's been almost a year since I quit working on BLE. So I only answer this question based on my memories.

Basically @dominik has it right.

If the device is freshly new, it should advertise normally (without setting the whitelist only bit), then any central device could connect and bond. Once it is bonded, you should save this bonded flag and the bonded master's bd_addr to EEPROM. If the next time the master is lost, you will advertise with that white-list-only flag set. If a new central tries to connect, you could verify if its address is the same as your master.

I don't have the BLE spec at hand and I kind of forgot a lot about BLE already. Probably the spec says somewhere that if a central sees a peripheral device is broadcasting with white-list-only flag set, it wouldn't try to connect if it doesn't recognize that peripheral device. This saves both some effort.

But a master could always initiate a connection to your peripheral device regardless the white-list-only flag. So checking if the connecting central device's address is the same as your previously bonded master is the last resort.

[Update]

I used CSR1010 chips. I remembered that the BLE stack actually allows me to insert a list of bd_addr to the white-list data structure maintained by the stack. Then, with the white-list-only flag set, the lower-level stack layer will help you filter devices that are not in that white-list without your knowing.

However, you can always filter bd_addrs from your application code.